# java class leve exception handling - catch exceptions of all methods in single place

Tags: java

I have a Java exception handling design question .

I have a Backing layer(java bean class) in my web app.
I would like to catch the exceptions(RunTimeE) thrown by all the methods in a class in single place.   My backing bean class extends the AbstractBackingBean class.

Is there any way ,can i catch the exceptions from all the methods and log it in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For a web application you can do that in a `Filter`:

```
public void doFilter(..) {
  try {
      chain.doFilter(req, resp);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
       // do something
   }
}
```

If a filter is not an option for some reason, take a look at AOP. For example spring has good [AOP support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). It's similar to the filter approach, but you specify exactly which classes and methods you want to attach the handler to.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I will look in to to and let you know...Our app is JSF2 in weblogic , i guess i can put a filter ...